# Why is the amu of chlorine-35 less than 35?

Tags: atoms

My book says that a proton weighs 1.0073u, a neutron weighs 1.0087u, and an electron weighs 0.00055u.

Now, why is the mass of chlorine-35 equal to 34.969? Are there not 17 protons, 18 neutrons, and 17 electrons? I calculated it and it sums to around 35.29. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It did not go wrong. The average mass per nucleon decreases toward iron, and then increases toward uranium. Where do you think nuclear fusion and fission take their energy from ? Check masses of 4He and 16O, or Fe isotopes.

Comment: hi! my book said that all protons are the same weight, so goes with neutrons and electrons. where did i go wrong when I simply added the weights?

Comment: You have not counted mass loss due their bound energy. $\Delta E = \Delta m \cdot c^2$

Comment: oh cool! my book did not teach about that yet, so good to know. Thanks for helping me! :)

Comment: [Related question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32119/1499) and answer.

Comment: E.g. hydrogen to helium stellar fusion means loss of 0.7% of the mass.

Comment: Every proton and neutron is loosing a small part of their masses when they are included in a nucleus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the energy released when nucleons and electrons come together and form a Cl-35 atom. Its called the Binding Energy.

This sort of equation can help to explain :

(Rest Mass Energy of Individual nucleons,electrons*) - (Various Binding Energies) = (Rest Mass Energy of Natural)

*edit

Comment: ok thanks! i get it now, since the book did not say anything about binding energy.

Comment: Also, I used the term mass-energy. You can interpret it as actual mass, according to the mass-energy equivalence ( the famous E=mc^2 ).

Comment: @12345bird As mass of subatomic particles is used to be expressed in equivalent units of energy, usually MeV.

Comment: *should be:*  (Rest Mass Energy of Individual particles, neutons, protons and electrons) - (Various Binding Energies) = (Rest Mass Energy of Natural Nucleus) // *The electron binding energies are small compared to the nuclear binding energies, but easily measurable today.*

Comment: Oh noted, I'm not really up to date on new technologies. I'll make the appropriate edit. Thanks!